# Read/Write HFS+ Partitions in Windows

Tags: windows, mac, hfs+

Is there any way or software to read/write HFS+ partitions in Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have used [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/software/macdrive) in the past, but I recently stumbled upon [this free method](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20101112214346176) (assuming you have a Mac OS X install disc). Looks good, but I haven't had a chance to test it.

Note: *The free method uses the Boot Camp driver in the OS X install disk. 
It seems to be read-only and for the Intel processor only
(i.e., it doesn't work with an AMD-based processor).*

Answer (score 9):

[MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive) or [HFS for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/), [TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) are all good options, there is also [HFSExplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html) - it is free, but only provides read access.

Answer (score 3):

Paragon's HFS solution appears to be the optimal solution in this case; it's free and provides the most features at no cost.

Here is a direct link:
https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows-free/

Most of the other options cost around 20 USD...

Comment: That now redirects to their regular product page, which says “you can try HFS+ for Windows by Paragon Software for ten days completely for free. After that it will be locked until you activate a purchased license.”

Comment: Just can't win. They used to have a free version. Now I have to go find a link to the legacy version...

Comment: I thought I found it, but it was only for Win 7. Let us know if you find something better.

Answer (score 1):

This freeware program is called Linux Reader but it also supports HFS, HFS+, and APFS.

https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/

This is the best free option as of today.