# Storage disk format to use to be utilised by all OS

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, storage

Aiming to have a large internal HDD to store files, and several OSes on separate disks. They all need to read and write to one storage drive.

```
Ubuntu (13.04+)
Mac OSX (10.8+)
Windows (7+)
```

What format should the drive be? Would like to avoid buying third party software, here's what I have discerned so far:

- NTFS - Can't be written to by Mac without buying third party
  software?
- ext3 - Windows can't read, [third party software in development](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/access-ext4-ext3-or-ext2-partitions-in.html). Mac has [OSXFUSE](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57457850-263/how-to-manage-ext2-ext3-disks-in-os-x/)
- HFS+ - [Buy third party and/or faff around to get working on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/330850/read-write-hfs-partitions-in-windows)
- exFAT - [Cross platform](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4605709), but [breaks MS patents?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Disadvantages)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform file system](http://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system), http://superuser.com/questions/235753/filesystem-to-use-for-external-hard-drive-to-be-used-with-mac-linux-and-windows?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/105485/what-is-a-file-system-which-has-r-w-on-all-major-oses?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally I would now recommend to use [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT); it's supported on the three major OSes and supports large files and a large number of files.

But if you want to use NTFS, you don't have to buy anything.* See [How to copy files to read-only NTFS hard drive on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/338607/how-to-copy-files-to-read-only-ntfs-hard-drive-on-a-mac/338618#338618) – there are non-commercial programs to write NTFS on Macs. Just install `ntfs-3g` via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and follow the instructions that you're given on the command line. You'll also need [osxfuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/).

Then, you can use NTFS without problems, and also don't run into an issue with large files. With `ntfs-3g`, NTFS volumes will be mounted with read/write support, and in practice I've never experienced problems with it.

<sub>* There are commercial variants that promise better speed and support, like Tuxera and Paragon, but they are not strictly required.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If I had to do something like that I will go for a spereate NAS drive.  You can setup up [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/).  This has the ability that you can write from different OS'es to one storage.  You may need a seperate machine for this, apart from the one with the 3 OS'es on.

Comment: The OP does not want to buy third party software… so I don't quite understand why you're suggesting to buy a *separate machine* just to share files on a computer?

Comment: Software != hardware. Any 6 year old machine would do the trick and knowing that OP needs to work with 3 OSes shows that he is not new to the computer world. Thus a big possibility of him having old tower, laptop, even raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1):

just do FAT 32 with no security will be okay.

Comment: a better solution is to partition them to 3 drive, there is no point to transfer file between difference OS.

Comment: There are quite a few reasons to transfer files between different OSes – if only because you have different tools on different platforms to work with the same dataset.

Comment: This would work! But limited to 4GiB

Comment: I will just put those thing in google drive. by the way, i never multi-boot since VM was there. and when using VM, it just drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with StBlade, it seems to me that this is the best option.

This being said, if you are adamant on keeping your disk attached to your pc, I would go with NTFS, which is a journaled, fully POSIX-compliant file-system. Even the problem with Mac OS is probably less severe than you might think because, short of buying a commercial solution, you can enable writing on NTFS systems on Mac OS, for instance [following this guide](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57588773-263/how-to-manually-enable-ntfs-read-and-write-in-os-x/).