# How to read a Mac or Linux hard drive on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, filesystems, ext

I have a Hard Drive. But I don't remember what is there. I think is Linux File System or MacOS File System.
How I can see what is on that Hard Drive using Windows or some LiveCD ?

Comment: This looks like two separate questions, one duplicate is https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows and another is https://superuser.com/questions/330850/read-write-hfs-partitions-in-windows

Answer (score 3):

If it is a Mac formatted drive, it is probably a HFS(+)-partition. To read it in Windows (for free), you can use [HFSExplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/) by Catacombae. It requires Java though, which can be found [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/) if you don't already have it installed.

If it is a Linux formatted drive, there are multiple applications that support Ext2/Ext3 available.

Here's two of them:

- [DiskInternals Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)
- [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)